# Why does this code not respond promptly to changes in the LDR reading?

Tags: c++, neopixel

So, I wrote some simple code like this :

```
void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);
  Serial.println(LDRValue);
  delay(50);
}
```

The line will print the value of LDR sensor simultaneously, but when I add this "if" condition inside the loop :

```
 if (LDRValue < 100) {
   colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50);
   colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50);
   colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50);
   colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50);
   theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50);
   theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50);
   theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50);
   rainbow(20);
   rainbowCycle(20);
   theaterChaseRainbow(50);
  }
```

the LDR  value only printed once..

Is it a wrong "if" condition code ? I know it's kinda lame, but please give me some starting point, doesn't need to be fancy just a small lead will do, thanks!

***edit :*** [complete library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/examples/strandtest/strandtest.ino)

Comment: Guess: Try putting the delay before serial.print(). Sometimes LCD can prevent serial from working for a short time.

Comment: How are your functions inside the if block implemented? With delays?

Comment: Visual Micro, it has nothing to do with LCD tho, @gre_gor its just looping one after another, no delays in it. It's a LDR + WS2812b LED code, with neopixel library if anyone else need extra information.

Comment: Did you try @VisualMicro's suggestion of putting a delay in?

Comment: How are you supplying power to the ledstrip? Does it work without the strip attached? It may be that you're trying tot supply the ledstrip with power from the Arduino, and it may simply dip if you try to set the leds on.

Comment: Alternatively the code may loop endlessly or get a watchdog timeout.

Comment: You ought to post your complete code if you hope for a good answer rather than best tries and guesses at best. What is `strip`, how are all values declared and initialized, where do all functions `colorWipe`... come from?

Comment: Your code matches [this example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/examples/strandtest/strandtest.ino) and those functions are blocking execution with delays.

Comment: Thank you all for your concern, and gre_gor, thanks for pointed the real problem, is there anything i can do so the LDR value could printed normally? what should i change? `void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}`

Comment: After all effect, the value should be printed neverthless?  You said it would only print once?

Comment: that is correct Paul, my mistake, it does printed again after all the loop called, never waited that long before you pointed that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to lever off gre_gor's comment on the question.

The code you are calling (for example, `rainbow`) has delays in it:

```
void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

So we can see straight away that calling `rainbow(20);` is going to take at least 20 x 256 ms (256 iterations of the loop with a 20 ms delay) plus more because of whatever else it does. That is over 5 seconds already!

Then you call `rainbowCycle(20);` and then `theaterChaseRainbow(50);` so you won't get back to the main loop for a while.

How to fix? Well, it isn't just a case of adding a line or two. One solution is to rewrite without delays, but instead have a state machine.

An alternative would be to test the sensor in each loop. Let's guess your objective is to stop the display if the LDR gives a higher reading. You could copy/paste the functions in question, but test the LDR inside them, eg.

```
void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {

    int LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);   // <--- add these 3 lines
    if (LDRValue >= 100)
       return;

    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

---

### Suggested improvement to example

The code below uses a technique of supplying a "callback function" to the functions that do the pixel displays. I modified the Adafruit example to show the idea:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
  #include <avr/power.h>
#endif

#define PIN 6

typedef bool (*AbortFunction) ();


// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = Arduino pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)
//   NEO_RGBW    Pixels are wired for RGBW bitstream (NeoPixel RGBW products)
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(8, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// IMPORTANT: To reduce NeoPixel burnout risk, add 1000 uF capacitor across
// pixel power leads, add 300 - 500 Ohm resistor on first pixel's data input
// and minimize distance between Arduino and first pixel.  Avoid connecting
// on a live circuit...if you must, connect GND first.

void setup() {
  // This is for Trinket 5V 16MHz, you can remove these three lines if you are not using a Trinket
  #if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
    if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  #endif
  // End of trinket special code


  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}


// function prototypes
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort = NULL);
void rainbow(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort = NULL);
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort = NULL);
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort = NULL);
void theaterChaseRainbow(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort = NULL);

const byte LDRSensor = 0;

bool checkLDR ()
  {
  int LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);
  return LDRValue > 100;
  }

void loop() {
  // start with black
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 0); // Black

  // Some example procedures showing how to display to the pixels:
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50, checkLDR); // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50, checkLDR); // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50, checkLDR); // Blue
//colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0, 255), 50); // White RGBW
  // Send a theater pixel chase in...
  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50, checkLDR); // White
  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 0, 0), 50, checkLDR); // Red
  theaterChase(strip.Color(0, 0, 127), 50, checkLDR); // Blue

  rainbow(20, checkLDR);
  rainbowCycle(20, checkLDR);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50, checkLDR);
}

// Fill the dots one after the other with a color
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    if (fAbort && fAbort ())
      return;
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbow(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      if (fAbort && fAbort ())
        return;
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Slightly different, this makes the rainbow equally distributed throughout
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    if (fAbort && fAbort ())
      return;
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights.AbortFunction fAbort
void theaterChase(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort) {
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {  //do 10 cycles of chasing
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      if (fAbort && fAbort ())
        return;
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, c);    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

//Theatre-style crawling lights with rainbow effect
void theaterChaseRainbow(uint8_t wait, AbortFunction fAbort) {
  for (int j=0; j < 256; j++) {     // cycle all 256 colors in the wheel
    for (int q=0; q < 3; q++) {
      if (fAbort && fAbort ())
        return;
      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, Wheel( (i+j) % 255));    //turn every third pixel on
      }
      strip.show();

      delay(wait);

      for (uint16_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i=i+3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0);        //turn every third pixel off
      }
    }
  }
}

// Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
// The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
}
```

The important addition is to add another optional argument `AbortFunction fAbort` to each function call. The default is NULL, in which case the function behaves the same as before. However, if supplied, the function is called. If it returns `true` then the display function exits (thus avoiding the delays), like this:

```
if (fAbort && fAbort ())
  return;
```

The first test is "does the function exist?" and if so, the second test calls the function and checks to see if it returns true or false.

The modified example shows the scrolling patterns on the NeoPixels, provided A0 returns 100 or less. The function that does this is here:

```
bool checkLDR ()
  {
  int LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);
  return LDRValue > 100;
  }
```

That function is passed as an argument to the other functions, eg.

```
rainbow(20, checkLDR);
```

I have a [page about writing callback functions](http://www.gammon.com.au/callbacks).

Comment: i'll try this out now, i'll get back to you with the result in a couple hours, thank you very much everyone!!

Comment: Sorry Nick, i can't make it to try this out yesterday, but I went to your page and this solve the problem, thanks for the answer and your time to explain them all, thank you very much Nick, and everyone else here too!